# How to limit Bootstrap Combobox Search to match with only a minumum of 3 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I'm using [bootstrap combobox plugin](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) but I cant seem to find any documentation of how to apply the matcher option.

I need to limit the combobox to search with three or more entries because it freezes the page when the match results hit more than 20,000 entries. By default it starts searching on a single character.

Comment: Which combobox plugin? Is it using typeahead?

Comment: yes, this plugin https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox